# Disk Space and Cluster in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there any option to specify the disk space and cluster usage for each user while creating the user in redshift ?

Answer (score 0):

**Disk Space**

There is no capability in Amazon Redshift to limit users to specific amounts of disk storage.

Redshift uses PostgreSQL-like commands to grant/revoke permissions to database users. While tables are associated with an *owner*, it is not possible to limit the amount of disk storage used by tables associated with a user. In fact, it is not possible to restrict storage space by any parameter

**Cluster Usage**

There are two levels of control:

- Redshift API calls to launch and terminate clusters (plus other associated commands)
- Database-level commands that control whether users can create tables, query data, access views, etc

These controls limit whether a user is permitted to perform a particular operation, but do not limit the 'amount' of usage (eg disk space, concurrent queries).

See: [Redshift security documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/iam-redshift-user-mgmt.html)

Comment: Plus the Work Load Management options to limit Memory Allocation and Execution Time (limits apply to queues, users can be assigned to queues)